# javascript and d3.js variable scope: variable resets outside of function call

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I've read a few posts about variable scope and I can't seem to figure this out. Any help is much appreciated.

Basically, I'm just trying to read in a csv and determine how many rows it has and then assign number to a global variable. Here is my code:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">  
    var maxEpochs;

    setMaxEpochs();
    console.log(maxEpochs);

    function setMaxEpochs() {
        /*
        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            if ( document.chooseModel.model[i].checked ) {
                modelChoice = document.chooseModel.model[i].value;
                break;
            }
        }
        console.log(modelChoice);
        */


        // set initial value for maxEpochs I DON'T UNDERSTAND WHY THIS DOESN'T WORK
        d3.csv("epochStats.csv", function(d) {
            console.log(d.length);
            maxEpochs = d.length;
            console.log(maxEpochs);
        });
        console.log(maxEpochs);

    }

</script>
```

NOTE: `epochStats.csv` just has to be a csv with a few lines in it. That data doesn't matter for this example.

So, when I run this I get the following output in my console:

```
maxEpochsFail.html:31 undefined
maxEpochsFail.html:12 undefined
maxEpochsFail.html:27 101
maxEpochsFail.html:29 101
```

The line numbers might not quite match (I have some `<head>` tags etc at the top), but the point is, the first two console.logs within the function print `100` which is the correct number, but then once I'm outside the function it reverts to `undefined`.

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated. I'm kind of banging my head against the wall with it.
Thanks,
Seth

Comment: I won't close this question (yes, it is a duplicate!) because I feel sorry for your head being banged against the wall! Here is a good reading for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function . Please read Felix Kling answer to the end, it's worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the asynchronous nature of javascript. The blocks of code you write do not get evaluated "in order" as you might expect. Basically, anything that uses the `d3.csv` call HAS to be within that block:

```
d3.csv("epochStats.csv", function(d) {
        console.log(d.length);
        maxEpochs = d.length;
        console.log(maxEpochs);
        // anything else that uses the value of maxEpochs, or reads the file data, etc....
});
console.log(maxEpochs);  <-- This could be evaluated before the above csv block.
```

Comment: I see. So, what is the best way to handle this if I need to have that function run _before_ the other functions (because I need to set `maxEpochs` and I have to load a csv file to set it)? Right now I am just have `onload="setMaxEpochs(); anotherFunction(maxEpochs);"` in the body tag of the page, but I guess that isn't working.

Comment: One  option would be to have everything within the d3.csv function call, that seems to be quite common with d3.

Comment: Ok, I figured out a solution:
If a call `onload="setMaxEpochs(); setTimeout(anotherFunction(maxEpochs),200);"` instead, then the 200 ms that it waits before trying the other function are enough time for it to set the `maxEpochs` variable. Someone can let me know if this is a bad idea for any reason, but it seems to work. Thanks to @tim-b for pointing out the asynchronousity being the issue!